# Error Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser on Kubernetes container

Tags: kubernetes, jasper-reports, yaml

After implementing `jasperreport 6.0.0` on `kubernetes` I am getting below error

```
Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
```

I have tried multiple solution but still the error is NOT getting resolved.

**Attempt 1:** setting `-Djava.awt.headless=true`

I have implemented this property in YAML file as metioned on
[how to add CATALINA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true this property in Kubernetes configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59286855/how-to-add-catalina-opts-djava-awt-headless-true-this-property-in-kubernetes-co)
but it did not work.

I tried setting in system property as well `System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true")` but his also did not worked.

**Attempt 2:** Including missing dependency for `xml-apis`. It also did not work.

Attempt based on [this thread](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/825173/could-not-initialize-class-netsfjasperreportsengineutiljrstyledtextparser).

Can someone please suggest any solution? The report is working absolutely fine in local environment but getting failed on server. The application is deployed on Kubernetes container

Comment: Please provide more information. Are you using cloud provider(which one)? What kubernetes version. What command did you use to implement `jasperreports`, from what image?

Comment: 1) Are you using cloud provider - I am using Google Cloud
2)  What kubernetes version -  we are using kubernetes version 1.12.10-gke.17
3) What command did you use to implement jasperreports - We want to generate excel reports using Jasper so we created microservices in java with Jasper and deployed in kubernetes using YAML configuration

Comment: Add full stacktrace so we see the root cause